# How does Find Usages choose which modules it searches?

Tags: intellij-idea

My project was created from an maven project, with additional external maven modules added as I discovered that it was useful to have other source files at hand.

The source for interface X lives in module-library.  If I navigate to the source file, highlight the X.execute() signature, and then invoke Find Usages (Project Files), a get a list of the usages in module-library.

The source for the application Y lives in module-app.  If I navigate to the source file, find a place where X.execute is invoked, highlight that usage, and then invoke Find Usages (Project Files), I get a list that includes usages in module-app, and also the usages in module-library.

Shouldn't these be the same?  Does the fact that they are different imply that I've somehow screwed up the creation/configuration of my project?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, I've [reported it in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99841). Please login to the tracker and provide more details (like your IDEA version/build number). Sample project to reproduce this problem would help a lot.

You can also check if `File` | `Invalidate caches` helps.